# WSMO based Semantic Web Service repository?

Tags: web-services, semantic-web

I am in need of a dataset containing several WSMO/WSML based web services for testing a service discovery algorithm.

I've tried searching online, but unable to locate any WSMO repositories.

Does anybody have any idea whether there is a publicly available free repository of WSMO based semantic web services? somewhat similar to the OWL-S service repository as given in http://projects.semwebcentral.org/frs/?group_id=89&release_id=380

Comment: Please note that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."  You might have better luck with this on http://answers.semanticweb.com

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thank you very much! for the link. I will keep in mind, your advice about off-topics for future questions.